# Convert regex for comma separated value to CFG grammar

Tags: context-free, formal-grammars, regular-expressions

I have the following regex that I'm trying to convert to a CFG: `e|a(,a)*` (`e` representing the empty state). Basically I want to match a comma-separated list (without a leading or trailing comma) or nothing at all. Here are some of my attempts:

```
S = A
A = e | a | a , A
```

This doesn't work, it matches `,a` (leading comma).

```
S = A | B
A = e
B = a C
C = , C | a | e
```

This doesn't work either, it matches `a,` and `aa` (trailing and missing comma).

Is my regex even representable as a CFG?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the heart of your regex is an alternation {$\alpha|\beta$), which means that the regex matches $\alpha$ or $\beta$. That's how you should write the CFG:
$$\begin{align}S\to&\;\alpha\\
|&\;\beta
\end{align}$$
Here, $\alpha$ is $\varepsilon$ and $\beta$ is the subexpression $a(,a)^*$, for which we'll define the non-terminal $A$.

It's easy to see what $A$ is: it starts with an $a$ and can be extended arbitrarily with $, a$:
$$\begin{align}S\to&\;\varepsilon\\
|&\;A\\
A\to&\;a\\
|&\;A\;,a
\end{align}$$

Comment: thank you so much!